# Rails 3.1 has_one nested resource: routing not generating "all" paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-resources

I have a has_one relation:

```
# supplier.rb

  has_one :presentation
...

# presentation.rb

  belongs_to :supplier
...
```

and the folowing nested routes for them:

```
# routes.rb

resources :suppliers do
  resource :presentation
end
```

running `rake routes`gives:

```
    supplier_presentation POST ... {:action=>"create", :controller=>"presentations"}
 new_supplier_presentation GET ... {:action=>"new", :controller=>"presentations"}
edit_supplier_presentation GET ... {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"presentations"}
                           GET ... {:action=>"show", :controller=>"presentations"}
                           PUT ... {:action=>"update", :controller=>"presentations"}
                        DELETE ... {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"presentations"}
```

**Why no name_helper for the show action?**

I can override the problem doing something like:

```
resources :suppliers do
  resource :presentation, :except => :show do
    get "" => "presentations#show", as: "presentation"
  end
end
```

giving the route:

```
presentation_supplier_presentation GET ... {:controller=>"presentations", :action=>"show"}
```

but we all now that's not the right way to deal with it..

**ANY SUGGESTIONS?**

--

**(edited)**

```
supplier_presentation_path(@supplier)
```

does work, but **why?**... It doesn't appear when `rake routes` is executed on my shell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont really know why it's not displayed when you do `rake routes` but did you try in your code to do `supplier_presentation_path(@supplier)`? It should work based on your routes.

Comment: It does work, but **why** it's not reflected when doing `rake routes`

Comment: I dont know, maybe because it's the same as the POST. I tried it on one of my projects, and it's not displayed either.

Answer (score 0):

Never the less it should work for you. Try this:

```
link_to "Presentation", [@suplier, @presentation]
```

or

```
link_to "Presentation", suplier_presentation_path(@suplier, @presentation)
```

Comment: You dont need the @presentation when using supplier_presentation_path since supplier has_one presentation ;)

Comment: @Robin, oh, that's true. I didn't notice this relation