# Rails 4 - routes for nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, routes, nested-routes

I am trying to make a navbar in my rails 4 app.

When a user registers, I want to automatically build a profile for that user.

I have models for user and profile. The associations are:

```
user has_one profile
profile belongs_to user
```

I'm struggling with the automatic build, but I have a different question now.

In my navbar, I have a link to the users profile.  I'm trying to figure out how to get that link to work.

I have routes as follows:

```
 resources :users do
     resources :profiles
  end
```

I have also tried my routes using profile (singular), as:

```
resources :users do
    resources :profile
end
```

In my navbar, I have:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
                    Hi <%= link_to(current_user.first_name.titlecase, user_profile_path(@current_user, @profile)) %></span>
                <span class="deviselinks" style="padding-right:30px">
                    <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></span>

                  <% else %>
```

I have also tried without the '@' symbols, as:

```
Hi <%= link_to(current_user.first_name.titlecase, user_profile_path(current_user, profile)) %></span>
```

I have also tried:

```
Hi <%= link_to 'current_user.first_name.titlecase', [@current_user, @profile] %></span>
```

To me, this appears consistent with the rails guide example: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

When I try this, I try creating a new user, but I get this error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Nil location provided. Can't build URI.):
2015-12-28T21:08:51.228286+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-12-28T21:08:51.228279+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:               <ul style="text-align: right">
2015-12-28T21:08:51.228287+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-12-28T21:08:51.228280+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:                 <span class="deviselinks" style="padding-right:30px">
2015-12-28T21:08:51.228281+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:                   <% if user_signed_in? %>
2015-12-28T21:08:51.228282+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:                     Hi <%= link_to 'current_user.first_name.titlecase', [@current_user, @profile] %></span>
2015-12-28T21:08:51.228282+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:
```

When I try the navbar path as:

```
Hi <%= link_to 'current_user.first_name.titlecase', user_profile_path(@current_user, @profile) %>
```

I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>nil, :user_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id, :user_id]):
```

Can anyone see how to set this up properly so the navbar links to the current users profile show page?

When I rake routes for grep profile, I get:

```
user_profiles GET       /users/:user_id/profiles(.:format)          profiles#index
                         POST      /users/:user_id/profiles(.:format)          profiles#create
        new_user_profile GET       /users/:user_id/profiles/new(.:format)      profiles#new
       edit_user_profile GET       /users/:user_id/profiles/:id/edit(.:format) profiles#edit
            user_profile GET       /users/:user_id/profiles/:id(.:format)      profiles#show
                         PATCH     /users/:user_id/profiles/:id(.:format)      profiles#update
                         PUT       /users/:user_id/profiles/:id(.:format)      profiles#update
                         DELETE    /users/:user_id/profiles/:id(.:format)      profiles#destroy
```

ANOTHER ATTEMPT

When I try changing the nav bar link to:

```
Hi <%= link_to 'current_user.first_name.titlecase', user_profile_path(@user, @profile) %></span>
```

I get the same error as I set out above.

ANOTHER ATTEMPT

When I try changing the nav bar link to:

```
Hi <%= link_to 'current_user.first_name.titlecase', user_profile_path(@user_id, @profile_id) %></span>
```

I get the same error as I set out above.

ANOTHER ATTEMPT

When I try changing my routes to:

```
devise_for :users, #class_name: 'FormUser',
             :controllers => {
                :registrations => "users/registrations",
                # :omniauth_callbacks => "users/authentications"
                :omniauth_callbacks => 'users/omniauth_callbacks'
           }

  # get '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'users/authentications#create'
  # get '/authentications/sign_out', :to => 'users/authentications#destroy' 

  # PER SOURCEY TUTORIAL ----------
  match '/users/:id/finish_signup' => 'users#finish_signup', via: [:get, :patch], :as => :finish_signup
resources :users do
     resources :profiles, only: [:new, :create]
  end
resources :profiles, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

And changing my nav bar link to:

```
 Hi <%= link_to 'current_user.first_name.titlecase', profile_path(@profile) %>
```

I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):
```

When I try the nav bar link as shown in the suggestion below:

```
Hi <%= link_to (current_user.first_name.titlecase, profile_path(@profile)) %></span>
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError (/app/app/views/pages/_nav.html.erb:14: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
2015-12-28T22:14:54.726458+00:00 app[web.1]: ...rent_user.first_name.titlecase, profile_path(@profile)) );@o...
2015-12-28T22:14:54.726459+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                               ^
2015-12-28T22:14:54.726460+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/views/pages/_nav.html.erb:14: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
```

When I try changing the nav bar link to:

```
            Hi <%= link_to ('current_user.first_name.titlecase', profile_path(@profile)) %></span>
```

I get another syntax error as:

```
SyntaxError (/app/app/views/pages/_nav.html.erb:14: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
2015-12-28T22:33:53.457021+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-12-28T22:33:53.457014+00:00 app[web.1]: ...ent_user.first_name.titlecase', profile_path(@profile)) );@o...
2015-12-28T22:33:53.457015+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/views/pages/_nav.html.erb:14: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
2015-12-28T22:33:53.457015+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                               ^
2015-12-28T22:33:53.457016+00:00 app[web.1]: ...ase', profile_path(@profile)) );@output_buffer.safe_append='...
2015-12-28T22:33:53.457017+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                               ^):
```

ANOTHER ATTEMPT

When I try following the ideas in this post:

[User profile pages with devise - Routing to show action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449573/user-profile-pages-with-devise-routing-to-show-action)

I change my navbar link to:

```
        Hi <%= link_to 'current_user.first_name.titlecase', current_user_profile_path %></span>
```

I then get this error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `current_user_profile_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f4337749f60>:0x007f4337749358>):
```

ANOTHER ATTEMPT

When I try changing  my navbar link to:

```
 Hi <%= link_to('current_user.first_name.titlecase', profile_path) %></span>
```

I then get this error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"} missing required keys: [:id]):
```

I'm going to go crazy trying to learn to code.

NEW RAKE ROUTES FOR PROFILE IS:

```
edit_profile GET       /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)           profiles#edit
                 profile GET       /profiles/:id(.:format)                profiles#show
                         PATCH     /profiles/:id(.:format)                profiles#update
                         PUT       /profiles/:id(.:format)                profiles#update
                         DELETE    /profiles/:id(.:format)                profiles#destroy

           user_profiles POST      /users/:user_id/profiles(.:format)     profiles#create
        new_user_profile GET       /users/:user_id/profiles/new(.:format) profiles#new
```

When I start it up and press new user, the logs show this get command:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up"
```

Comment: For building a path for nested resources you should provide `:user_id`

Comment: What does that mean? I should replace @current_user with @user_id?

Comment: Can you post the output for `rake routes`?

Comment: Hi elements, I added them above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest only nesting some profile actions, like this:

```
resources :users do
    resources :profiles, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

and then using top-level routes for the other actions:

`resources :profiles, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

If you have the `current_user`, you can pass just that user's `profile` to those actions instead of both.  Of course, your path names will change and you'll have to change those in your views.  (Something like `Hi <%= link_to(current_user.first_name.titlecase, profile_path(@profile)) %>`).

I'm curious, though, why have what appears to be a link to the user lead to the user's profile?  Why not link to `Users#show`, using `user_path(@current_user)` or whatever your equivalent route is, and then just rendering the profile on the `Users#show` view?

Comment: So how would I setup the navbar link with this approach?

Comment: @user2860931 Just added an example link for you to try.

Comment: I tried this - chaining the routes and the link as you suggested. I get this error:(No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):
I'll copy it above so it's neater to read

Comment: To answer your question. I have a user model (for attributes that users won't change) and a profile model, for attributes that users may want to update. I don't have a view page for users. I just have one for profiles. So I want to go there.

Comment: @user2860931 You're getting the syntax error because you have a space between `link_to` and the parenthesis.  What is your new `rake routes` output and when you click the new link, what is shown in your server logs (should start out with something like `Started GET ...`)?

Comment: @user2860931 Actually, once you fix the syntax error, check to make sure that @profile is actually getting set.  That seems like the most likely cause.  Try this:  `<%= link_to(current_user.first_name.titlecase, profile_path(current_user.profile)) %>` to see if that's the case.

Comment: Hi, yes, I found the space. I added it because it's shown like that in the other link I posted. I'm still in all sorts of mess with the functionality of this.

Comment: Thank you! That way worked. I would love to understand how you knew to try that formulation. It doesn't look anything like what's in the rails guides.

Comment: It was just one way to try to get it working, and something that was used on a project I worked on previously.  You could probably use your original routing and link and pass `current_user.profile` or make sure `@profile` gets set and use that and it should also work (like this answer and comments explain: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7029769/2599738).  You mentioned something about going crazy learning to code...don't worry, that feeling is 100% to be expected.  Just keep at it and you'll be fine.